# ajax in ruby on rails for a like/unlike button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, haml

So i have a page with a like button under my comments and am trying to work out how to do this without refreshing the whole page currently the code looks like this:

```
- if can? :like, comment
  = " · "
  - if likes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).nil?
    = link_to "Like", like_comment_path(comment), method: :post
  - else
    = link_to "Unlike", unlike_comment_path(comment), method: :post
- if comment.user == current_user
  = " · "
  = link_to "Delete", comment_path(comment), method: :delete,
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?" }
- if likes.count > 0
.comment-likes
  - likers = likes.map { |like| link_to(like.user_name, "#") }
  - if likers.length > 1
    - likers = likers.slice(0, likers.length - 1).join(", ").concat(" and " +                               likers.slice(-1))
  - else
    - likers = likers[0]
  = "Liked by #{likers}".html_safe
```

Changing the method for like and unlike :post to :update seemed to make a big difference is this function using ajax and :post not? If not then how would i go about making this into a ajax function.

Heres my comments_controller.rb stuff

```
def like
 comment_vote = resource.like current_user
 Event.comment_liked!(comment_vote)
 redirect_to discussion_url(resource.discussion)
end

def unlike
 resource.unlike current_user
 redirect_to discussion_url(resource.discussion)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`= link_to "Like", like_comment_path(comment), method: :post, remote: true`

Then in your likes_controller create action, respond_to format.js

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { .. your liking code .. }
    format.js {.. your liking code .. }
  end
end
```

This will then invoke the create.js.erb in your view folder, and you can dynamically update your html from there

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this working i have included my comments_controller.rb file in the question above if you could give me some direction to go with my like and unlike functions that would be great @Amir